# Unable to Create New folder/File in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, disk, partitioning

I tried various option suggested in different forums to resolve the issue,  without any luck.

Snippets of command  that I have used:

```
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media/alex/Y
[sudo] password for alex: 
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo chmod 755 ~/
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:~$ chmod u+w ~
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo chmod -Rf 777 /dev/sda5
```

Unmounted and mounted the drives several time ,still the error exist.

(P.S.) I am able to create new folder and file under Home, Desktop, Document, Downloads, Music and Pictures. but cant create in any of the drives.

Tried creating the file with console:

```
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Y/Blockchain$ mkdir abc
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: Read-only file system
```

on runing the **mount** command gave the following result:

```
/dev/sda5 on /media/alex/Y type fuseblk 
(ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)

/dev/sda4 on /media/alex/X type fuseblk 
(ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)

/dev/sda6 on /media/alex/Z type fuseblk 
(ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

As I understand ro stands for read only, hence tried to unomunt and mount the drive.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda6 /media/alex/Z
```

Got the following output:

```
mount: /media/alex/Z not mounted or bad option
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What file system ? chown / chmod will not work at all with FAT and not with NTFS unless you use permissions.

Comment: Its NTFS format

Comment: How did you mount it exactly? Just plugging it in, or manual mounting?

Comment: You can `sudo mount -o remount,permissions /dev/sda6 /media/alex/Z` Then you can use chmod and chown . See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: @dobey I mounted using the disk utility option. @panther- Did as you suggested, still no luck,  while creating a new folder through UI got the message "Disk is read only", through terminal got the message  `alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Z$ mkdir abc
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: No such file or directory` 
 User, Group and others all have rwx permission on all the drives `alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct 26 17:29 X
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov  1 20:56 Y
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov  1 22:21 Z`

Comment: Is the disk full, is there a ro button on the disk ? what happens when you `sudo mkdir abc` ?

Comment: No the disk is not full.  Not sure how to check the ro button. (Disk is inside the laptop)
`alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Z$ sudo mkdir abc
[sudo] password for alex: 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: Read-only file system`.  Also after every restart the create new folder link is disabled.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/OksFi)-Click on the link to see the error message when trying to copy/create a file/folder through UI